# Not able to get results for spotlight search for user tags with NSMetadataquery and kMDItemUserTags

Tags: swift, macos, tags, spotlight, nsmetadataquery

I am at my wits end after trying to add a routine to my controller to search the user's computer for user files with specified user (Mavericks+) tags. I am running into a block where the search will start, but no results are returned and the operation queue is nil.

Here is the code:

```
class myController: NSWindowController {

    //define metadataQuery 
    var metadataQuery: NSMetadataQuery!
    var metadataQueryDidUpdateObserver: AnyObject?
    var metadataQueryDidFinishGatheringObserver: AnyObject?

    //initialize notificationsCenter
    let notificationsCenter = NotificationCenter.default

func doSpotlightSearch(){

    //add observers
    notificationsCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "initalGatherComplete:", name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: nil)
    notificationsCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "batchReturned:", name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate, object: nil)


    metadataQuery = NSMetadataQuery()
    metadataQuery.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryIndexedLocalComputerScope]
    metadataQuery.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "kMDItemUserTags == 'myTags.testTag'")

    //start search
    metadataQuery.start()

    //test to see if query is up and running
    while metadataQuery.isGathering{
        print(metadataQuery.operationQueue?.operationCount)
        print ("result count: \(metadataQuery.resultCount)")
        sleep(1)
    }

func batchReturned(_ sender: NSNotification) {
    print("Running batchReturned func")

    let resultCounter = metadataQuery.resultCount
    print("Number of results:\(resultCounter)")
    let notificationsCenter = NotificationCenter.default

    notificationsCenter.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: nil)
}

func initalGatherComplete(_ sender: NSNotification) {
    print("Running initialGatherComplete func")

    metadataQuery.stop()
    let resultCounter = metadataQuery.resultCount
    print("Number of results:\(resultCounter)")
    let notificationsCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationsCenter.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering, object: nil)
}
```

When I run the above code, it shows the results queue as being nil and the result count as zero.  Even if I take out the isGathering loop, the batchReturned and initialGatherComplete functions never get called.

I suspect that there may be an issue with the predicate formatting, but this works fine when I put the query into the terminal with mdfind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation of `NSMetadataQuery.start()` method: `This method must be called from the receiver’s operationQueue or on the main thread.`

If you are not calling `start()` method from main thread you are responsible to create `OperationQueue` yourself and start if from there, e.g:

```
// Declare on class-level
private lazy var queryOperationQueue: OperationQueue = {
  let queue = OperationQueue()
  queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1 // restriction for NSMetadataQuery
  return queue
}()


...

func doSpotlightSearch() {
  metadataQuery = NSMetadataQuery()
  metadataQuery.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryIndexedLocalComputerScope]
  metadataQuery.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "kMDItemUserTags == 'myTags.testTag'")

  // assign queue to NSMetadataQuery
  metadataQuery.operationQueue = queryOperationQueue

  // run query from its queue
  metadataQuery.operationQueue?.addOperation {
    metadataQuery.start()
  }
}
```

Hope it's clear.